# how to add bearer access token in request header from controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I'm working on Laravel API Authentication. I have done login, register part. when I want to get-details of any user using `postman` every time i need add `Bearer access_token` in request header.

But I want to send it from my Backend `Controller` or `Middleware` .
How can i do this.

Here is my Code Sample. I try this way But not working.

```
public function details(Request $request) 
{ 
     $user = Auth::user(); 

      $token='Bearer '.$request->bearerToken();
      $request->header('Authorization',$token);

      return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this-> successStatus); 


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this in middleware, for example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AccessTokenMiddleware
{
   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       $request->headers->add(['Authorization' => "Bearer {$request->access_token}"]);

       return $next($request);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's registered as a `Global` or `route` Middleware ?

Comment: @Gabrielle route group

Comment: where is this `access_token` come from? word `access_token`